# JavaFX controls inside TableView behaving strangely - bug raised

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Bug raised https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8088542

When trying to add editable functionality to a JavaFx editable TableView, using the following test case code that I have written: -

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Foo extends Application implements Runnable
{

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) 
  {
    final TableView table = new TableView();
    final TableColumn column = new TableColumn();
    table.setEditable(true);
    column.setEditable(true);

    table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList());

    column.setCellFactory(cell -> new EditableComboBoxCell());
    column.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleStringProperty("foo"));

    table.getColumns().add(column);

    // Simple thread loop to demonstrate adding items

    new Thread(() ->
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.sleep(20000);
                Platform.runLater(() -> table.getItems().add("foo"));
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
        }
    }).start();

    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(table));

    stage.setScene(scene);

    stage.show();

  }

  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    launch();
  }
}
```

where 'EditableComboBoxCell' is: -

```
public class EditableComboBoxCell extends TableCell<String, String>
{

  private ComboBox<Object> comboBox;

  @Override
  public void startEdit()
  {
    super.startEdit();
    comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    setGraphic(comboBox);
  }

  @Override
  public void cancelEdit()
  {
    super.cancelEdit();
    comboBox = null;
    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    setText(getItem());
  }

  @Override
  public void updateItem(final String item, final boolean empty)
  {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (empty)
    {
      setText(null);
      setGraphic(null);
    }
    else
    {
      if (isEditing())
      {
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        setGraphic(comboBox);
      }
      else
      {
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        setText(getItem());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I find that if the items are dynamically added, every second, the combo box disappears when the next item is added. I have tested this by adding a new item every few seconds. This code works perfectly fine when the JavaFx TableView contains static data.

I have observed this behavior on Java 8u45 and Java 8u60 (early access).

I have looked around and found that there is a bug with items not being updated in the tableview and that the fix is to set the column to invisible then visible again however this hasn't fixed the problem. Furthermore, that fix seems to be resolved in 8u60 and I'm still observing this behavior.

Does the JavaFx tableview not cope well with controls being displayed when the tableview is constantly having data added/removed? Is there any work around?

Comment: please show a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Sorry, though that was enough to demonstrate the problem, I'll add a little more. I assume you don't need static void main/launch etc??

Comment: Please go through on how to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: sure I need everything to _quickly_ run the sample and see what's going wrong ;-) BTW: you have a severe error in the first snippet (was it there before your edit?) - all modification of fx components (including their data!) MUST happen on the fx application thread ..

Comment: as an aside: any reason you don't use the ComboBoxTableCell? It looks like it can be configured to be editable (nver tried, though)

Comment: Unfortunately I need some custom functionality that the default doesn't have; the test case should be runnable now and yes, Platform runLater is now there.

Comment: ok, so, the code above demonstrates a fully working example that shows the problem. Run the above, wait for an item to be added (blank) and then double click on a cell. Wait until the next item is added and observe that the combo box closes.

Comment: hmm .. looks like editing is canceled on modification to the items (replace your custom comboCell with a core TextFieldTableCell). Would consider such behaviour a bug - unsuccessfully argued for decades in Swing ;-)

Comment: Actually looks like this was introduced as a fix for https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-37853. This "fix" just cancels editing if the table contents change. Probably it should be more sophisticated: if the content change removes the item that is being edited, cancel edit, otherwise make sure the correct cell is now in editing state.

Comment: yes James_D, that sounds like it would fix the problem; I'll raise the bug

Comment: raised https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-40736

Comment: Bug is tracked with new JIRA-number: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8088542